# Importing SPSS to R and Keeping Data Types

Tags: r, date

When I import a dataframe from SPSS to R using this code, dates are turned to a long numeric number.

`read.spss("data.sav", to.data.frame = TRUE, use.value.labels = TRUE, col.names = columns)`

I've tried all of the following, but they just give NAs.

`as.Date(df$var, format = "%d-%m-%Y")`, `as.Date.numeric(df$var, format = "%d-%m-%Y")`, `mutate(df$var=as.Date(df$var, format = "%d-%m-%Y"))`, `as.POSIXct(df$var, format = "%d%m%Y")`

Does anyone know how to either import SPSS files to R and keep dates or change a long numeric to date?

Comment: Where does `read.spss` come from?

Comment: from the package foreign